# How to get sum of a column based on the values of two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table as bellow with 3 columns. Sample data is given

```
column_1    column_2    column_3
   A           a           10
   A           b           20
   B           a           10
   A           a           10
   B           a           30
   A           b           40
   A           c           10
   C           a           20
```

I want to get the sum of column_3 based on the values of column_1 and column_2. Which means I want to get the sum of values in column_3 which are having 'A' for column_1 'a' for column_2 and so on..

```
Sample output is given bellow
     column_1    column_2    SUM(column_3)
       A           a              20
       A           b              60
       A           c              10
       B           a              40
       C           a              20
```

Can someone please tell me how to do this

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(column_3), column_1, column_2 FROM table GROUP BY column_1, column_2
```

The `GROUP BY` command states that you want to group the aggregate function (`SUM`) using distinct values of the columns which names follow the `GROUP BY`. It is not "required" that they also appear in the `SELECT` portion of the query, but it is good practice (and the only way of knowing which row represents which grouping.

Obviously replace `table` with the actual table name.

Answer (score 0):

can you use group by with col1 and col2 and sum the col3 like below

```
SELECT   SUM (col3)
    FROM test_table
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Answer (score 0):

`select column_1, column_2, SUM(column_3) from table 
group by column_1, column_2`

group by allows you to apply an aggregate function to a column based on groupings of other columns.

Thinking backwards, `group by column_1, column_2` can be thought of as: "give me all unique combinations of column_1 and column_2. Selecting `SUM(column_3)` will then take the sum of  the entries in column_3 for each group.

Answer (score 0):

Create an helper column with the concatenation of the columns that you have the criteria.

From there you can only summarize the criteria that match your needs!

Please use the below line as well in your logic:

```
with t1 as ( select col1
        , col2
        , col3
        , col1||'-'||col2 as help1
        from Table1)**
        
select T1.help1
        sum (T1.col3) as Sum_col3
        
from T1
where T1.help1 in ('A-a')
group by T1.help1
order by 1
```

Comment: For the coloring issue, you can use 3 ` before and after the formatted content. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score -1):

try out this...

```
SELECT SUM(column_3), column_1, column_2 FROM table   
GROUP BY column_1, column_2
```

Comment: It should contain all the records. Not only 'A' and 'a'